# Desactivar botones de paginación Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-validate

Como puede desactivar los botones anteriores cada vez que se presiona el botòn siguiente, de tal forma que al presionar los botones hacia atrás ya no se visualice el contenido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberias de incluir tu codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que seria mas facil si usaras el `pagingStyle: simple`.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$("#table").dataTable({
  "pageLength": 3,
  "pagingType": "simple"
});
```

```css
.dataTables_paginate a.paginate_button.previous {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Apellido</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Nombre1</td>
<td>Apellido1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre1</td>
<td>Apellido2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre1</td>
<td>Apellido2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre1</td>
<td>Apellido2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre1</td>
<td>Apellido2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que tienes la siguiente tabla:

```
 <table id="ejemplo" role="grid" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Apellido</th>
              <th>Edad</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <!--información proveniente de base de datos -->
      </tbody>
  </table>

<script>
$('#ejemplo').dataTable({
  "bPaginate": false, //Ocultar paginación
})
</script>
```

Que necesitas? Ubicar el `id` de tu tabla. En el caso de anterior el `id` de la tabla es `id="ejemplo"` y luego en tu script de configuración de la ***dataTable*** colocas `"bPaginate"` que es el que se encarga de la paginación en `false` para ocultarla.

Por otro lado si lo que deseas es deshabilitar la paginación entonces debes utilizar el siguiente script:

```
<script>
$('#ejemplo').dataTable( {
    "paging": false
});
</script>
```

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!